# Select elements of last (dynamic) row?

Tags: html, css

I have a container and some rows. I give them margin-top with the [* + * selector](http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls) which works fine:

```
> * + * {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

The Problem ist when I have **columns** inside this rows - how do I dynamically detect the last "row" of columns (kitten images) in my example with only css to delete their margin-bottom? I don't think there is a proper solution but maybe someone could tell me an alternative way to do this. Here is the pen:

http://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/xOwmWZ

(Bootstrap grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lobotomized owl do not act on kittens margin because of `>`.

Just replace *margin-bottom* with *margin-top* and add

```
*:nth-child(-n+4){
    margin-top:0;
}
```

to remove margin-top from first 4 elements.

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZNyOy)

Also I changed 1em with 2em to keep vertical / horizontal margins equal.

Comment: Why didn't I saw this xD - Yes, this is a very good solution! Only drawback is that I have to know the number of columns in a (gallery-) row (in this case 4). But I think there is no better solution so thanks a lot!